# filter rownames with substrings on match

Tags: r

I have a column named IsomiR and I want to select those rows which has I-C in the third position in the rownames of this column. Why do I get integer(0) from my command?

```
IsomiR
hsa-miR-200b-3p_AATACTGCCTGGTAATGATGACA 0 I-C t C

grep("^(?:[^ ]+ ){3}I-C",topIsomiRSignAveExpr$IsomiR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `grep` will return a vector of the indices of the elements of x that yielded a match. Indices => numbers. In your particular case, you get integer(0) because your regex doesn't work.

If you want to filter, I'd rather suggest using `grepl`, e.g. like that:

```
topIsomiRSignAveExpr <- topIsomiRSignAveExpr %>% 
  filter(grepl(".* .* I-C", IsomiR))
```

Comment: If your are going to use the pope operator you should make that clear by including code to load pkg:maggritr.